# $R[x]$ has a subring isomorphic to $R$

Tags: abstract-algebra, polynomials

> $R$ is a commutative ring. We need to prove that $R[x]$ has a subring isomorphic to $R$.

Let $S$ be that subring of $R[x]$ which has polynomials of even degree. Now I consider a mapping from $S$ to $R$ as : $f(x) \to f(0)$ where $f(x)$ is a polynomial of even degree and $f(0)$ is clearly in $R$.

The mapping defined as above "seems" one-one and onto. But I couldn't prove it.

I took the kernel of the mapping as $\ker \phi = ( f(x) \in S | \phi ( f(x)) = 0 )$ , 
Which only gives $a_0 = 0$ , 
$ f(x) = a_0 + a_1 x + a_2 x^{2} $ . . . ... $ a_n x^{n} $

We know if kernel only contains the " 0 " element then the mapping is one-one . But I'm unable to prove that here. Can anyone help me out here ?

Comment: I see no reason for your mapping to be one-one. For example. $f(x)=a_0$ and $g(x)=a_0 + x^2$ both map to $a_0$.

Comment: Why dont you use the constant polynomials?